# Ssl Certificate ERR::NET_CERT_REVOKED error on GoDaddy

Tags: ssl-certificate

I have my client purchased for an SSL Cert on GoDaddy but sometimes it shows this error on some computer, `ERR::NET_CERT_REVOKED`. I asked GoDaddy but they did not reply yet while my client is pushing me. Any help on this please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your SSL Certificate is not revoked or cancelled by certificate authority, then you may have some solutions. Main issue with the certificate revocation in chrome is that the client machine is being blocked from contacting the revocation servers for getting the website SSL certificate.

First find the actual reason behind the revoke, here are some reasons-

- Your private key has compromised
- The SSL Certificate had been not issued properly
- Failed identity verification

**Solution**
Try this tip first
Windows \ Mac \ Chromebook
Menu > History > Clear browser data (Choose Browsing History, Download History, Cookies, Cached images)

Once the SSL Certificate revoked, it’s not possible to get it back and you may have to purchase a new one. However, the SSL is not permanently revoked, you can contact your SSL provider to reissue and replace new SSL Certificate files on the web server and remove the all old SSL Certificate files. It may solve your issue.

Answer (score 1):

I had same issue 2 weeks ago, I was told to reinstall and it works for me